# Transform data to xml with different schemas

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb, sax

I need to convert a List of records(java objs) into XML output. The XML schema can change based on the request type and the xml output needs to be in a different format with different elements based on the request parameter (Eg. Request A -> produces xml in format A`<A><aa>name</aa></A>` Request B -> format B `<B><bab>name</bab></B>`). The existing framework uses JAXB but the dataobjects are tightly coupled with one XML schema.

We are trying to refactor to make it flexible so that based on the request type, we can generate different xml outputs. i.e. same data -> multiple output formats. We are also expecting more xml schemas, so we need to keep it flexible.

Appreciate if you could please let me know which framework would be most suitable for this type of scenario.  What would be a good solution for huge schema and data files.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So you have your Domain Model and one or more Integration Models (output formats). I assume, when you create a response (Integration Model), you use some kind of adapter from Domain Model (if not, you should consider this). I would keep it this way for multiple Integration Models (response types / output formats).

For each response type, have a dedicated Integration Model (e.g. generate it from a XSD, e.g. with JAXB) and have an adapter from your Domain Model to this Integration Model.
Then, based on request type, select one of the adapters and produce the response.

If you want it to be really futureproof, you should consider to have your own Integration Model for the app. This will prevent you from making changes to the adapters whenever your Domain Model changes, like this:

Domain Model -> [trafo] -> Common Integration Model -> [trafos] -> 3rd Party Integration Models

By the way, converters don't need to be implemented in one particular technology, use what best fits a particular case. One adapter may use JAXB generated Java classes, other may be a XML Transformation.

You may consider implementing your integration layer with frameworks like [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will try the recommendation you have mentioned above and also look into Apache Camel and post back if I have further questions.